# How to analyze the current AEM dependencies on the package at runtime?

Tags: java, aem, trace, jcr

My goal would be to create mechanism to print the stack trace to a log file that records every time the "data" node in the **JCR** is accessed by **AEM (CQ)** code.

But I just to try work with **AEM** and I don`t know how to do it correct...

Possible solutions how I might do this:

- With help aspectj
- Custom ResourceResolver

Please provide me example how I  can do this...
I also hope  get more ideas and links to resources  that will help me.

Comment: I sense a requirement that might be solvable another way. Do you want to share what you are trying to achieve? Why do you need to know, when someone accesses the "data" node?

Comment: Define dependencies. A content package might contain anything ...

Comment: @Jens, In future we going to remove legacy code... and we need analyze dependencies... Tracing which we get we need to save in log file in "data" node

Comment: Not sure I get this. I guess you are using Maven? Why don't you use Maven to figure out which of your content packages have dependencies to other bundles/packages etc? AEM is never going to have dependencies on _your_ packages. It will run without them. So only _your_ packages/bundles can have dependencies on _your_ packages/bundles. And it is probably a lot easier to figure those out using Maven or whatever you use.